# Activity restart when unlock android device

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android application I am starting the activity using broadcast receiver. If my device lock during this activity and if I unlock it  then activity restart mean it run on create again
Please help me to solve this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you implemented `onPause();` and/or `onStop();` methods? If so are you saving app state? And what device you're using?

Comment: i have added toast in on create method and i m getting every time when i unlock device

Comment: @chester1000 which app state i should save and how can i prevent by using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml?
I think u should appoint launchMode to "singleTask" like that:

```
<activity android:name=".Youracticity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

^-^

Comment: now i have one problem after using this solution. in activity i am showing video in full screen but after i unlock the device video cant see in full screen

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest do you have anything like this:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />

        <receiver android:name="com.activities.app" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

If yes, then please handle it properly.

Answer (score 0):

**for detect screen on and screen off register a broadcast reciver like:**

```
<receiver android:name="receiverScreen">
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
<action android:name="android.Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

**In Activity or Service:**

```
try {
          IntentFilter if= new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

          if.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
if.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

          BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new receiverScreen();

          registerReceiver(mReceiver, if);
     } catch (Exception e) {

     }
```

**receiver code where System inform you if Screen on/off happen:**

```
public class receiverScreen extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){

     }
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){

     }
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){

     }
 }

}
```